# android RelativeLayout for all devices

Tags: android, scale, android-relativelayout

I am trying use relative layout for some android application.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:background="#ff394aff"
        android:text="start"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"

        android:id="@+id/start" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.50"/>
```

but the in some devices will appear in a different positons. I tried "dip" and "sp" but the problem remains.
help me how to do it so that in all devices the positions be same?

Comment: position of button change or relativelayout?

Comment: position of button :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get when you are using marginleft then why u are using gravity to center horizontal.?
try this which ever the device is , button will come at the bottom of the page with full width to screen. In this xml you can see a listview with a back button on its bottom fixed and i have tested it u can put what ever you want in the place of list and adjust button position accordingly, hope this may help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="1dip"
android:paddingLeft="1dip"
android:paddingRight="1dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cback"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cback"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many device have different resolution, so problem in your code is marginleft and margintop. Due to them your button position is different in all device.
Also android:layout_weight="0.50" should not be used in Relative layout. It will have no affect.

Comment: OK! so how to fix button on a position. independent resolution?

Comment: you can use android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"                         these property for positioning your button. or try to create dimens.xml for resolution you want to support